# Комплексная выборка нужных данных из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть несколько таблиц: **Station**, **Train**, **Schedule**.

Вот их определение:

```
CREATE TABLE Train (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    seats INT
);

CREATE TABLE Station (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30)
);

CREATE TABLE Schedule (
    id INT,
    dateDeparture VARCHAR(10),
    dateArrival VARCHAR(10),
    stationDeparture INT,
    stationArrival INT,
    train INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, stationDeparture, stationArrival, train)
);
```

Мне надо написать такой запрос, который будет вытаскивать все поезда, которые идут в определённый временной промежуток (поиск поезда, проходящего от станции **А** до станции **В** в заданный промежуток времени). Т.е опираясь на `dateDeparture`, `dateArrival`, `stationDeparture`, `stationArrival`, мне надо выбрать все поезда из таблицы.

Так-же, для примера, вот так таблицы заполнены:

```
INSERT INTO Train (id, seats) VALUES (1, 20), (2, 15), (3, 45);

INSERT INTO Station (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Saint-Petersburg'), (2, 'Helsenki'), (3, 'Moscov');

INSERT INTO Schedule (
    id,  dateDeparture, dateArrival, stationDeparture, stationArrival, train
) VALUES 
    (1, '12-09-18', '05-08-18', 1, 2, 1),
    (2, '13-01-19', '12-01-18', 1, 3, 2);
```

Никак не понимаю, как мне написать нужный запрос с использованием *JOIN*'ов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Train.id AS id, S1.id AS s1_id, S2.id AS s2_id, S1.name AS s1_name, S2.name AS s2_name, dateDeparture, dateArrival
  FROM Schedule
  JOIN Train ON Schedule.train = Train.id
  JOIN Station S1 ON S1.id = Schedule.stationDeparture
  JOIN Station S2 ON S2.id = Schedule.stationArrival
WHERE S1.name = 'Saint-Petersburg'
  AND S2.name = 'Moscov'
  AND dateDeparture >= '13-01-19'
  AND dateArrival <= '15-01-18'
```

Можно в `SELECT` только `id` или больше параметров выбрать. Если нужно только id поезда то `Train` джойнить и не надо

Comment: Ваш запрос не выдаёт ничего

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bad21d1/16 у меня по структуре с вопроса все работает, ```WHERE``` правильно настройте под ваши нужды и данные в базе

Comment: извините, это я накосячил. У Вас всё работает